# Question about Chinese hip-hop song

Tags: translation

I was listening to this song by the group Yin Tsang (隐藏) -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvzAtKPF-Xk  At 4:17, the song ends and there is a brief interview with one of the rappers in the group.  The sound quality is scratchy and I can't really understand it all.

Can anyone transcribe what the rapper is saying in the interview?

Answer (score 4):

你知道我们为什么签京文旗下的嚎叫唱片吗

我们这个乐队叫隐藏

为什么叫这个名呢

我们以前什——任何人不知道我们

但是我们知道我们自己的能力在哪

那么我们本身——我们自己听音乐

我们自己什么音乐基础 什么音乐的意见都借鉴了

我们会作比较

别的东西跟我们的东西会作比较

我们会比出一个好坏

所以我们知道我们自己能力在哪儿

那 你知道你能力在哪儿以后 你有了信心以后

你就可以 完全地去 发展你自己的东西了

你不用顾忌太多

如果你 做一个音乐事儿 哎 我想有一万个人听我的音乐

那你这样你做不出来音乐

那你 如果你 第一你做音乐事儿

我*这音乐是我自己做的 我都不敢相信

在那个时候 那个就是艺术了